# Dereferencing a temporary unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

```
unique_ptr<A> myFun()
{
    unique_ptr<A> pa(new A());
    return pa;
}

const A& rA = *myFun();
```

This code compiles but `rA` contains garbage. Can someone explain to me why is this code invalid?

Note: if I assign the return of `myFun` to a named `unique_ptr` variable before dereferencing it, it works fine.

Comment: Since you are not storing the `unique_ptr` that `myFun` returns, its destructor is called at the end of the expression, and the object it owned is freed.

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly I saw that in the dessasembly, I don't understand how is the destructor call triggered.

Comment: [As seen on TV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEx5DNLWGgA#t=44m2s)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `unique_ptr` will pass the ownership to another `unique_ptr`, but in your code there is nothing to capture the ownership from the returning pointer. In other words, It can not transfer the ownership, so it will be destructed.
The proper way is:

```
unique_ptr<A> rA = myFun(); // Pass the ownership
```

or

```
const A rA = *myFun(); // Store the values before destruction
```

In your code, the returning pointer will be desructed and the reference is refering to an object which is destructing soon, after that using this reference invokes an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 7):

```
unique_ptr<A> myFun()
{
    unique_ptr<A> pa(new A());
    return pa;
}

const A& rA = *myFun();
```

What you did on that last line:

```
unique_ptr<A>* temporary = new unique_ptr<A>(nullptr);
myFun(&temporary);
const A& rA = *temporary.get();
delete temporary; // and free *temporary
```

When you delete `temporary` it has a contract with you that *it owns the pointer and the memory that refers to*. So it destructs the `A` and frees the memory.

Meanwhile, you've sneakily kept a pointer to that memory as a reference to the object at that address.

You could either transfer the pointer to a local unique_ptr:

```
unique_ptr<A> a = myFun();
```

or you could copy the objects:

```
A = *myFun().get();
```

The 'A' to which `myFun()`s temporary is only destructed at the close of the statement, so it's present for the copy.

Comment: I am a bit confused. What is `unique_ptr<A>*`, a raw pointer points to a `unique_ptr`? `myFun` doesn't take any arguments, why is `myFun(&temporary)` valid?

Comment: @MiloLu : It's pseudocode demonstrating the lifetime of `myFun`'s return value.